# Disconnect from EventSource not working

Tags: java, playframework, server-sent-events

I have a Play 2 (2.3.7) app that uses EventSource connections. Everything works fine except when I try to close the connection from the client. To do that I am using the [ES.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource#Method_overview) method, but even after I disconnect Play only detects that the connection was closed (and processes the onDisconnect callback) when I send a ping to the client. Closing the connection from server side works as expected.

I tried this in Chrome/Firefox (using native implementation) and using [Yaffle ES polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/) and the result is the same. Both client and server are running in a linux machine.

**EDIT:** After closing the connection in the browser console and inspection the network tab in dev tools it seems the connection is indeed closed by the browser. So this may be a problem of Play?

So what may be the problem here?